# Office 365 Developer program mini-labs: instructions are out of date / incomplete?

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I have been looking at the 2 mini labs for the Office 365 Developer program (see http://dev.office.com/mini-labs).  But the instructions don't seem as good as they should be - can anyone help please?

In the second minilab part 4 Step 3, the screenshot for the showImages code seems incomplete - does anyone know where the full code can be found please (and preferably text rather than an image).  (Given that the page claims to enable users to develop apps within 5 minutes, why haven't Microsoft made it easier for users by allowing them to copy/paste code rather than just providing screenshots?

Note re minilab 1: the screenshots here seem to be out of date. The Api Sandbox link seems to be under the Resources menu, not the Documentation one as shown in the mini lab screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

I agree, not all labs are up to do. This is the latest code labs that we have few days in Build 2016 conference for Office 365:

https://github.com/Microsoft-Build-2016/CodeLabs-Office

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct these are out of date - the team is working on it. We will have some pointers to this year's //build coding challenges up very soon.  The code labs links above were instructor led code labs that may not solve the goal of getting started quickly that you may be looking for.

For now, I suggest you try one of the getting started flows on dev.office.com to get started with the Graph, Add-ins or Connectors.